# Install Python Pandas in an other folder

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to install the Python library "Pandas" in a specific target because my app use his Python interpreter.
Usually i do :

```
pip install --target=path/to/folder/lib pandas
```

Pandas is well installed in the lib folder but when i add my library i have an error

```
import os,sys
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(dir_path, 'lib'))


ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

Comment: Is it ok to install those packages to your admin folder and copy paste it to your project dir whenever you want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use pip to install it and take a look at pypi : https://pypi.org/project/pandas/

Just try whether it works or not.

Comment: It's what i do : pip install --target=path/to/folder/lib pandas. And before "import pandas" i update my sys.path to append the "lib" path. Error is always there.

Comment: Thanks @super-byte , i've found the problem. My pip was broken. After an update, it's works great

Answer (score 1):

Try using Venv or Virtualenv (if you are using version 2.7)

This will install in a folder inside you admin folder (by default)

Comment: It doesn't resolve my problem. When i create a venv it only make an isolate environnement. But i don't need that. I need to install pandas in a specific folder and when i add to path my folder, python "normally" will be able to resolve paths. The error that i have it's that i can't install correctly pandas with pip

Comment: Ok. It seems that it has downloaded the source code and asks to build it first.